# Scraping a large list of names using "rvest" (JavaScript Dynamic Webpage)

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have been attempting to scrape spell names and spell information from a website using 'rvest', but only get "**{xml_nodeset (0)}**" from anything that I select with SelectorGadget or with the css paths that I provide from the "inspect page" right-click option. I am using *R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)* and I have attempted various combinations of the following:

```
library(rvest)

url <- read_html("https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Spells%20List#content")

#All the spell names:
spells <- html_nodes(url,"#pagecontent a") #"#pagecontent a" is the result from selecting a name with SelectorGadget

#Details about a single spell, not able to select with SelectorGadget:
spell_descr <- html_nodes(url,css="#pagecontent > div.list-content > div:nth-child(1) > div.card > div > div.body > div.single-list > ul > li:nth-child(6)")
```

I am new to, but familiar with web scraping html and have been successful on other sites, however for some reason this one is failing to isolate nodes, almost as if the contents are missing entirely. I have examined the url object in R and it appears as if the only thing being returned to R from the site is the search box at the top of the web page.

My Questions are:

1. Is this website even able to be scraped?
2. If so, what am I doing wrong?
3. What is a good way to solve this?

Examples or links to solutions would be of great assistance!

Comment: Welcome to SO! 1. aye. all web sites _can_ (technically) be scraped. 2. The content is indeed "missing" (the site uses javascript for dynamic loading along with `iframes`); 3. None. What you're doing is in violation of their technical control in https://roll20.net/robots.txt since `/compendium/compendium/getList` (in that file) is what the page uses to get the content you want. I suspect the site owners would be open to just providing you the raw data if you emailed them with your ultimate intention for the data. Also, avoid using Selector Gadget. It's leads folks astray more than it does help

Comment: Thank you for answering all of my questions and explaining what was stopping the site from loading! This explains why attempting to scrape this specific site has been a HUGE headache. I guess my final questions are in regards to how you have interpreted the html to find all of this out? Would you recommend that someone interested in web scraping take a short course in html? I tried to find out if it was against their terms, but this is not so easy to find. Thank you for your time in helping me with this!